# GNU make strange behavior

Tags: gnu-make

I have a simple Makefile:

```
VAR := aaa
include a.inc
VAR += bbb
```

and a.inc

```
some_target: $(VAR)
        @echo "refer to automatic var $^"
        @echo "refer to VAR $(VAR)"

aaa:
bbb:
```

and when I run make I see a strange print:

```
refer to automatic var aaa
refer to VAR aaa bbb
```

Seems that GNU make substitutes $(VAR) in prerequisites at the inclusion moment but $(VAR) in debug print in some later moment. Is this correct behavior ? Why GNU make acts in such non-intuitive way?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct and it isn't unintuitive (though perhaps not immediately obvious).

It works the same way as variables in every other language.

Try this shell example.

```
$ var=aaa
$ echo "${var}"
aaa
$ ev() { echo "${var}"; }
$ ev
aaa
$ var+=bbb
$ ev
aaabbb
```

You get the value of a variable as it exists at the time that you use it.

The difference between `tgt: prereq` and `@recipe line` in make is when the lines are evaluated.

The [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) goes into about this in [3.7 How make Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles). Specifically, for this situation, you want the very last sub-section `Rule Definition`.

Answer (score 2):

Make variables set with `=` (rather  than `:=`) are expanded when they are used.

When you run `make` first it parses the makefile and determines the targets and prerequisites. At that point VAR gets expanded to its current value.

Then it runs the first target, and executes the recipe for that target, at which point VAR is expanded again, but to its new value.

Answer (score 1):

GNU make evaluates makefile in 2 passes. Everything is evaluated at first pass, except recipes. Recipes are evaluated at the second pass. So, your reference to `$(VAR)` in `some_target`'s recipe is evaluated at the second pass, i.e. after the `+= bbb` was appended to `VAR`, which happened at the end of the first pass.

To achieve the behavior you wanted you can use the following techinique for defining your rule:

```
define rule
some_target: $(VAR)
    @echo "refer to automatic var $^"
    @echo "refer to VAR $(VAR)"
endef
$(eval $(rule))
```

Don't forget to use tabs for recipe lines.